# Django and/or Apache: serve (static) files with a different name

Tags: django, apache, static-files

I store a lot of files, using a hash as file name, but when a user wants to download it, I would like to be able to give the file a new name.

Let's say the user navigates to `www.myurl.com/userxy/files/some.pdf`. In the Django View for that url, I can now look up the correspondig file, which might be on the server on `.../files/46dfa12bbf32d523fbb3642dfee45bb4`.

So how can I now get this file to be served as `some.pdf` to the client? Do I have to copy the file first, and giving it a different name on the disc or can I somehow serve the original file? Is what I'm trying at all good practice?

I also don't know on what level (Apache or Django) this type of operation is best handled. But since I didn't find anything about this for Apache or Django, I would be interested in solutions for either of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting django docs [Telling the browser to treat the response as a file attachmen](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#telling-the-browser-to-treat-the-response-as-a-file-attachment), you should inform it in response:

```
>>> response = HttpResponse(my_data, content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
>>> response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="some.pdf"'
```

Comment: Awesome, this works great. Just what I needed. For everyone who tries this and asks himself, how to get the file to display in the browser instead of downloading it: apparently you can use `inline` instead of `attachment`. At least that worked for me.